# react, mobx observale map - computed in component render not firing

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a store with a `@observable` map. Data from this map is read using a `@computed` function.

```
export class Postopki {
  @observable data = new Map<string, PostopekObservableType>([]);
  @observable activeId: string;

  // gets the postopek data for the current active id
  @computed get getActive(): PostopekObservableType {
    const postopek = this.getById(this.activeId);
    if (postopek) {
      return toJS(postopek);
    }
    return {
      canView: false,
      canEdit: false,
    };
  }
  ...
```

Then I have another `@action` that sets a property on a object in the observable map:

```
@action setCenilecId = (idCenilec: string): void => {
    const postopek = this.getActive;
    postopek.idCenilec = idCenilec;
    // updates postopek data with the new idCenilec
    this.addPostopek(this.activeId, postopek);

    console.group('setCenilecId');
    console.log('new postopek data', postopek);
    console.log('postopek observable', this.getActive);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
```

Finally I am using my computed in the render of a component:

```
@inject('postopki')
@observer
class PostopekView extends Component<any, State> {
  render() {
    const postopek = this.props.postopki.getActive;
    console.log('Postopek view:', postopek);

    return (
      <StyledDiv>
        ...
      </StyledDiv>
    );
  }
}
```

When calling `setCenilecId` I get the updated data logged to the console using the `getActive` computed.

But the render function for `PostopekView` does not fire even though the return value for the computed is different.

Edit - this is the parent component for `postopekView` Component.

```
@inject('postopki')
@observer
class Postopek extends Component<any, State> {
  state: State = {
    isLoading: true,
    hasError: false,
    errorMessage: '',
  };

  // gets initial postopek data based on the id from props when component first mounts
  componentDidMount = async (): Promise<void> => {
    ...
  };

  // updates postopek data when a new id is passed from router
  componentDidUpdate = async (prevProps: any): Promise<void> => {
   ...
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoading, hasError, errorMessage } = this.state;

    return (
      <WithStatus isLoading={isLoading} hasError={hasError} errorMessage={errorMessage}>
        <PostopekView />
      </WithStatus>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Postopek);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your `render()` of `Postopki` where `PostopekView ` is called? Is the parent `render()` evoked?

Comment: @FortyTwo edit the question with the code. The parent's render function is not invoked :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why the computed did not fire...

I had this method that I was calling in the `@computed`:

```
  @action getById = (id: string): PostopekObservableType | undefined => {
    const postopek = (this as any).data.get(id);
    return postopek;
  };
```

After I referenced the observable in the method directly:

```
@computed get getActive(): PostopekObservableType {
    const postopek = this.data.get(this.activeId);
    if (postopek) {
      return toJS(postopek);
    }
    return {
      canView: false,
      canEdit: false,
    };
  }
```

Everything updates as expected.

No idea why tho...